# Code generated form in UITableView not showing

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have created a UITableViewController and a xib file for login without using storyboard. The xib contains a UITableView, which means I have to generate cells by my self. I setup the datasource and delegate for the UITableView and the generate form cells like this.

```
#import "SWFLoginViewController.h"

@interface SWFLoginViewController ()

@end

@implementation SWFLoginViewController

@synthesize userNameField;
@synthesize userPasswordField;
@synthesize user;
@synthesize password;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 2;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    switch (section) {
        case 0:
            return 2;
            break;
        case 1:
            return 1;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:nil];

    // Make cell unselectable
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    UITextField* tf = nil ;
    switch ( indexPath.row ) {
        case 0: {
            cell.textLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"ui.username", @"");
            tf = userNameField = [self makeTextField:self.user placeholder:NSLocalizedString(@"ui.username", @"")];
            [cell addSubview:userNameField];
            break ;
        }
        case 1: {
            cell.textLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"ui.password", @"");
            tf = userPasswordField = [self makeTextField:self.password placeholder:NSLocalizedString(@"ui.password", @"")];
            [cell addSubview:userPasswordField];
            break ;
        }
    }

    // Textfield dimensions
    tf.frame = CGRectMake(120, 12, 170, 30);

    // Workaround to dismiss keyboard when Done/Return is tapped
    [tf addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldFinished:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidEndOnExit];

    // We want to handle textFieldDidEndEditing
    tf.delegate = self ;

    return cell;
}



-(UITextField*) makeTextField: (NSString*)text
                  placeholder: (NSString*)placeholder  {
    UITextField *tf = [[UITextField alloc] init];
    tf.placeholder = placeholder ;
    tf.text = text ;
    tf.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo ;
    tf.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone;
    tf.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
    tf.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:56.0f/255.0f green:84.0f/255.0f blue:135.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
    return tf ;
}

// Workaround to hide keyboard when Done is tapped
- (IBAction)textFieldFinished:(id)sender {
    // [sender resignFirstResponder];
}

// Textfield value changed, store the new value.
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    if ( textField == userNameField ) {
        self.user = textField.text ;
    } else if ( textField == userPasswordField ) {
        self.password = textField.text ;
    }
}

#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.
    /*
     <#DetailViewController#> *detailViewController = [[<#DetailViewController#> alloc] initWithNibName:@"<#Nib name#>" bundle:nil];
     // ...
     // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
     */
}

@end
```

And the header file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SWFLoginViewController : UITableViewController <UITextFieldDelegate,UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>

// Creates a textfield with the specified text and placeholder text
-(UITextField*) makeTextField: (NSString*)text
                  placeholder: (NSString*)placeholder  ;

// Handles UIControlEventEditingDidEndOnExit
- (IBAction)textFieldFinished:(id)sender ;

@property (nonatomic,strong) UITextField* userNameField;
@property (nonatomic,strong) UITextField* userPasswordField;
@property (nonatomic,copy) NSString* user ;
@property (nonatomic,copy) NSString* password ;

@end
```

When I launching my app in iPod, there is nothing but background texture.

I have stuck at here for a while and I really have no idea what's wrong. Then I put a breakpoint at `numberOfRowsInSection` and it was't hit all the time.

Please help.

Comment: That probably means that the datasource is *not* connected correctly.

Comment: @MartinR I connected the datasource to `SWFLoginViewController`.

Comment: check xib: "Custom class" class is set up as SWFLoginViewController.

Comment: Your cell reuse identifier is set to nil? Don't you like to optimise for performance?

Comment: Did you set the tableview's datasource and delegate?

Comment: @Abizern It is not used for mass data but forms. I think it is not needed.

Comment: Unless your form fits entirely on one screen, the cells will be scrolling on and off the visible view. In which case it is helpful.

Comment: @Abizern Thanks for your advise. there is only 2 rows in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After setting up your datasource (array or equivalent) you should make at least one call to `[yourTableView reloadData]`.

Since here you don't have any such data source, it would be good to call it from within `viewDidAppear` or `viewDidLoad`. Better there be a UITableView property and outlet within your login view controller file, and you have then a point to make this call.

Comment: Thank you. It works somehow with nothing. `numberOfSectionsInTableView` and `numberOfRowsInSection` called but `cellForRowAtIndexPath` did't called.

Comment: Glad to help. If it resolved, kindly mark as correct which will be quite helpful to you in getting answers quickly in future. As for 'cellForRowAtIndexPath', did you ensure 'numberOfRowsInSection' doesn't return 0?

Comment: On my previous note, your numberOfRowsInSection has a bug in it - case 1 falls through to default because there is no break in it. As a result, the function returns 0, which in turn causes cellForRowAtIndexPath not being called.

Comment: I assumed return in switch does not need break. I fixed this issue but  got noting on the table view. I am sure it is not the problem of `numberOfRowsInSection`.

Comment: I kind of find it strange. Is it possible for you to share your code for that view controller? I can try it on my box and see if I can help.